# Checking gcc warnings using Python

Tags: unix, os.system

Below is a small code segment in the python script I wrote. The purpose of the script is to compile various C files. (I modified the segment and simplified it to fit the purpose of the question.)

> ```
>     fileName = "somefile.c"
>     my_cmd = "gcc -std=c99 -Wall " + fileName[-2:0] + " .o " + fileName
>     os.system(my_cmd)
> ```

This works well. But I want to keep track of which file got compiled without warnings and which file showed warnings.

To check if the file compiled successfully is not a problem. I can either check the return value of os.system() or I can check if the corresponding object file got created or not.

But how can I check if the somefile.c had any warnings during compilation? Thanks!

**What I have tried:**

I tried using the ">" operator (redirection) but that is not working. I used something like:

```
os.system(my_cmd + " > output")
```

No matter what the contents of somefile.c are, the file named output is always created and is empty!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Processes in general get two output streams. One is `stdout`, has file number `1` and is (unsurprisingly) for standard output. The other is for errors and warnings and is generally called `stderr` and has file number `2`. To redirect the `stderr` in the shell you would do:

```
gcc file.c -o file 2> some_file
```

This will give you a file called "some_file" containing whatever gcc wrote to the stderr (including the information you want). Using this as a string with `os.system` would work but is *highly* not recommended. You should (almost certainly) use the `subprocess` module instead. Here is an example:

```
import subprocess as s

p = s.Popen(["gcc", "-std=c99", "-Wall", "test.c", "-o", "test"], stdout=s.PIPE, stderr=s.PIPE)

p_stdout, p_stderr = p.communicate()

print "*****STDOUT*****"
print p_stdout
print "*****STDERR*****"
print p_stderr
```